# Custom method API V2 is not a valid method for this service

Tags: api, extensions, soap

I created a custom method to the Magento SOAP API and it worked well so far. Now I want to create the same method to the Magento SOAP API V2.

I created the WSDL.xml and the V2.php Class files (below), and when I try call my method in V2 API, I got this error:

`Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("pacoteCreatelink") is not a valid method for this service in [...]`

Although the error be clear, it seems to me that my new method in soap v2 is not being recognized. I must pass something. Any Ideas?

**Files:**

```
Company
    Bundleapi
        etc
            config.xml
            api.xml
            wsdl.xml
        Model
            Pacote
                Api
                    V2.php
                Api.php
```

**V2.php:**

```
<?php
class Company_Bundleapi_Model_Pacote_Api_V2 extends Company_Bundleapi_Model_Pacote_Api
{
    public function createlink($message)
    {
        return $message;
    }
}
```

**api.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <bundle_link translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                <title>Create Bundle link</title>
                <model>bundleapi/pacote_api</model>
                <methods>
                    <createlink translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                        <title>Create link Options Bundle</title>
                    </createlink>
                    <cleanlink translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                        <title>Clean link beetwen Bundle and Simple Products</title>
                    </cleanlink>
                </methods>
            </bundle_link>
        </resources>
        <resources_alias>
            <pacote>bundle_link_pacote</pacote>
        </resources_alias>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <bundle_link>pacote</bundle_link>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
    </api>
</config>
```

**wsdl.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
<types>
</types>
<message name="pacoteCreatelinkRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"/>
    <part name="message" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
<message name="pacoteCreatelinkResponse">
    <part name="result" type="xsd:string" />
</message>
<portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <operation name="pacoteCreatelink">
        <documentation>Create Link to Bundle Products</documentation>
        <input message="typens:pacoteCreatelinkRequest" />
        <output message="typens:pacoteCreatelinkResponse" />
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="pacoteCreatelink">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
        <input>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
        <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Bundleapi>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Bundleapi>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <bundleapi>
                <class>Company_Bundleapi_Model</class>
            </bundleapi>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I have checked [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9499/how-can-i-create-a-custom-soap-xml-rpc-v1-v2-api-in-magento) and [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/magento-api-v2-methods-not-present) before.

Comment: you need a tag `v2` in `api.xml`. It is explained in the first link you said you tried.

Comment: I edited my `api.xml` with tag `v2`, but it's still not working. I edited question too. Thanks

Comment: I see nothing wrong at a first glance. I think a good place to start debugging is `Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler::__call`. See how the `$apiKey` variable looks like before calling the actual method. If it looks ok to you you can continue the debuggin g process in `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::call`

Comment: At a second look I see that you are also missing the `resources_alias` tag in `api.xml`.

Comment: I created `resources_alias` tag. I used the name of resource and de Model's name, looks like your code in your question. But still did not work. I'm starting to debug hot to you said. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Marius, I'm trying to debug it like you said but it still fails. My log commands are not being executed. My log settings are enabled and functioning normally in other parts of the store. Based on the current api.xml file (above), as would be the complete call my method? These `resources_alias` are leaving me confused. It seems that the error happens before, but my WSDL seems to be correct. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure about this but I think the resource_alias should be `<resources_alias>
            <pacote>pacote</pacote>
        </resources_alias>`

Comment: Thanks @Marius. The problem  was `v2` tag. About `resources_alias`, this alias system helps ensure API backward compatibility without code duplication. [More Info](http://alanstorm.com/debugging_magento_api_method_calls#highlighter_970218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem `resources_function_prefix` tag, in api.xml. This is responsible for specifying the prefix of the call in the format v2 for resource API v1. I was using it incorrectly.

My currently **api.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<api>
    <resources>
        <blink translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
        <title>Create Bundle link</title>
        <model>bundleapi/pacote_api</model>
        <methods>
            <createlink translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                <title>Create link Options Bundle</title>
            </createlink>
            <cleanlink translate="title" module="company_bundleapi">
                <title>Clean link beetwen Bundle and Simple Products</title>
            </cleanlink>
        </methods>
        </blink>
    </resources>
    <v2>
        <resources_function_prefix>
            <blink>blinkBlink</blink>
        </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>
</api>
</config>
```

Call in API V2: `$result = $client->blinkBlinkCreatelink($session,'string');`

For more infos: http://alanstorm.com/magento_soap_v2_adapter

Answer (score 5):

How did you connect through api?
If the value looks like http://example.com/api/soap?wsdl then you are still making a call to V1. Update it to look like this http://example.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl

Also, please, do not forget to refresh system cache.

If you wish to prevent future caching, use:

```
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0);
```

or dynamically:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://somewhere.com/?wsdl', array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE) );
```

Comment: I'm already using `ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", 0)`. In API V1 the call is: `$result = $client->call($session, 'bundle_link.createlink');`. These `resources_alias` tag in api.xml are leaving me confused. It seems that the error happens before, but my WSDL seems to be correct. Thanks for your help